# Android: Passing data between service class and particular activity?

Tags: android, android-service

```
Intent mIntent2 = new Intent(this,ChatActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);      
mIntent2.putExtra("drivername", nesname);       
mIntent2.putExtra("ij", ij);    
startActivity(mIntent2);
```

In this scenario, if it is not given:

```
Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

an error will be displayed. How to apply or pass values?

Comment: This isn't enough information to solve the problem. You should be able to start an Activity without needing those flags so I would assume the issue lies elsewhere in your code. What does your LogCat say?

Comment: In MainActivity class button click time i call this code       //code                     Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChatHeadService.class);
  it.putExtra("drivername", d_name);
  startService(it);

Comment: Cool deal, but what is your error? If the issue doesn't exist when you use `Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); ` I can only assume it is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: then the service executed. after In service class i will call new activity but i will pass some values service to new activity class. its possible?

Comment: new activity will be opened correctly but the values not received     new activity. new activity i will apply below code in oncreate function Intent intk=getIntent();
  
  if(intk !=null)
  {
   
   nesname=intk.getStringExtra("drivername");
   String jk=intk.getStringExtra("ij"); }

Comment: If it isn't crashing, and that is how you are handling your intent, I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Are Activity and Service on the same process/apk?

Comment: Service class used for display chat head icon that icon click time value passed in new activity

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Is it a single apk or more than one apk?

Comment: Single apk. i find out problem. integer value get time problem . solution intk.getIntExtra("ij", 0). Thanks